# how to use shared preferences in android.... i am a beginner so help me

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a beginner of android.. I am only good in designing an android app..  I don't know about shared preferences.. the very first time i have to use shared preferences,. So any one can do that in my code so that i can implement. The follwoing is my code and please make changes in my code: tell me how to save values onClick of button a that i m storing in different variable temporaryliy.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class newpage extends Activity {
    String un = null;
    String pass= null;
    String fname= null;
    String lname= null;
    String age= null;
    String city= null;
    String coun= null;
    String email= null;
    String pno= null;
    String repass= null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.create_acc);

            final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
             b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent i = new Intent(newpage.this, SignIn.class);
                        i.addFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
                        startActivity(i);
                 }
             });

             final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
             c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent i = new Intent(newpage.this, CreateAcc.class);
                    i.addFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                     }
             });

             final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
                    public void onClick(View v){

                        EditText input1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname1); 
                        fname = input1.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname1); 
                        lname = input2.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age1); 
                        age = input3.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input4= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city1); 
                        city = input4.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input5= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country1);  
                        coun = input5.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input6= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1); 
                        email = input6.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input7= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pno1);  
                        pno = input7.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input8= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname1);
                        un = input8.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input9= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd1);
                        pass = input9.getEditableText().toString();

                        EditText input10= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repass1); 
                         repass = input10.getEditableText().toString();

                        if((fname!=null) && (lname!=null) && (age!=null) && (city!=null) && (coun!=null) && (email!=null) && (pno!=null) && (un!=null) && (pass!=null) && (repass!=null))   
                        {   
                            if(pass == repass)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(newpage.this, ".....Data Saved....." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(newpage.this, SignIn.class);
                                    in.addFlags(
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(in);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(newpage.this, ".....Password Doesn't Match....." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }                   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(newpage.this, ".....Complete the Form Please....." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                  }
             });            
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have search in google http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read or write to `SharedPreferences` you first need to get `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

once you have the `SharedPreferences` you can write to them

```
prefs.edit().putString(KEY, VALUE).commit();
```

or your can read from them

```
prefs.getString(KEY, VALUE);
```

That's pretty much it. The TAG in preferences is just the name you're going to call your `SharedPreferences` - it can be any string. Everything is saved as a key value pair. You need to figure out where this goes in your code since I have no idea what you're trying to store.

Answer (score 0):

They are really simple.  You just called the `SharedPreferences` class to save and retrieve values.  It's best to only store simple values, anything complex should use `SQLlite`:

This code will save the email value:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("[unique id]", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

 editor.putString("email", email);
 editor.commit();
```

You would just have to create more `putStrings` for the other values.

This will retrieve the values:

```
 String email = settings.getString("email", null);
```

Comment: tell one thing i have a field of gender in my layout and that field have two radio buttons one male and other female then how to store the value that user clicks in???

Comment: @WasiKhn Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643485/how-to-implement-sharedpreferences-with-radiobuttons-in-android.  You basically create an `onClick` listener for either a submit button or on each radio button and save the value.  If you're creating settings for a user, might want to check out `Preferences` which handle saving the values for you and you would use a `ListPreference` instead of radio buttons.