# Storing of selected radio buttons on different screen in android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I am making a quiz app in which I have given radio buttons and at the last page there is a submit button, I want to store the selected radio buttons on button click.

pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);

```
    optionData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)mView.findViewById(R.id.group);
    ((TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textMessage)).setText(pageData[getArguments().getInt("pos")]);
    if(getArguments().getInt("pos") == 14) {
        ((Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.submitbtn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i)).setText(optionData[(getArguments().getInt("pos")*4)+i]);
    }
```

Comment: to store where? What have you tried so far?

Comment: in a shared preference, I am new to android so I have tried some or the other things found on SO or other links.

Comment: refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643485/how-to-implement-sharedpreferences-with-radiobuttons-in-android). There are a lot of resources in `SO` relling you have to do that. Please search before posting ay question.

Comment: Create a simple getter setter class and create object for that class on every answer and save that objects list, then on submit click retrieve every object and analyse and do what you want to do. Just to save some state I don't prefer using Shared Preference , its a costly operation.